# Create gallery bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to display kind of a gallery, with maximum two images per row, with a description of the image just beneath every image, I need it to be responsive, I'm not an expert with bootstrap, this is my code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">        
        <div class="col-md-6">  <a href="/Apps/Online" > <img src="~/images/aviation.jpg" style="max-height:300px;max-width:300px;" class="img-responsive" /> Aviation</a></div>
        <div class="col-md-6"> <a href="/Apps/Printable" > <img src="~/images/International_photo.jpg" style="max-height:300px;max-width:300px;" class="img-responsive" /> International</a></div>
        <div class="col-md-6">  <a href="/Apps/Online"> <img src="~/images/ship.jpg" style="max-height:300px;max-width:300px;" class="img-responsive" /> Marine</a> </div>
        <div class="col-md-6"> <a href="/Apps/Printable" > <img src="~/images/longshore.jpg" style="max-height:300px;max-width:300px;" class="img-responsive" /> WC/Longshore</a> </div>       
</div>
```

With the code above I'm getting the images of different sizes and they are not organized
I would like some responsive dessign like this:

```
    image                  image
  name_of_image          name_of_image

     image                  image
  name_of_image          name_of_image
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the existing Thumbnail-Class?
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#thumbnails-custom-content

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="..." alt="...">
      <div class="caption">
        Text here
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="..." alt="...">
      <div class="caption">
        Text here
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick way, with placeholders images :

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">        
     <div class="col-md-6" style="float:left;">  
        <a href="/Apps/Online" > 
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300" style="max-height:300px;max-width:300px;" class="img-responsive" /> 
        <div>
        Aviation
        </div>
        </a>
     </div>
    
     <div class="col-md-6">  
        <a href="/Apps/Online" > 
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300" style="max-height:300px;max-width:300px;" class="img-responsive" /> 
        <div>
        Aviation
        </div>
        </a>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-6" style="float:left;">  
        <a href="/Apps/Online" > 
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300" style="max-height:300px;max-width:300px;" class="img-responsive" /> 
        <div>
        Aviation
        </div>
        </a>
     </div>
    
     <div class="col-md-6">  
        <a href="/Apps/Online" > 
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300" style="max-height:300px;max-width:300px;" class="img-responsive" /> 
        <div>
        Aviation
        </div>
        </a>
     </div> 
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In the way the OP has asked, it seems that he has different images with different dimensions. in that case, your answer is not any good for him, because in your answer your images all have same dimension.